# Why does a select() call have a timeout? What are reasonable values for it in common scenarios?

Tags: c, sockets, posix, poll-syscall

I am wondering about the timeout value in a POSIX select() call. I understand why one may want value of 0 (for polling on the file descriptors). What other values are commonly used, and to what purpose?

Comment: There might be some housekeeping needed, such as closing inactive connections / filedescriptors, or scheduling keep-alive messages to the connected peers, or writing a summary line to a logfile, or saving program state in a statefile.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) is often better than [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) for multiplexing purposes (because the `FD_SETSIZE` is a strong limit for the highest file descriptor).

The practical timeout you'll use depend upon the situations. In many GUI [widget toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) frameworks, you know that the screen is refreshed at 50 or 60Hz, so you'll probably set the timeout accordingly (e.g. to 20 milliseconds). Or you know that the mouse should be followed at least 10 times per second, etc. In practice, these toolkits also have timeouts, so the `poll`  or `select`  timeout is computed dynamically at each cycle of the [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). In a web server, the timeouts are configurable, and the program would compute the `poll`  timeout accordingly.

In practice, the  [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) is often above a millisecond, and probably below a few dozens of seconds. YMMV. BTW, the exact timeout is often not very important.

See also the [*Answers* section of Norvig's *Teach Yourself Programming in Ten Years*](http://norvig.com/21-days.html#answers) webpage (a very interesting read).

Comment: I think the confusion is that you would expect a mouse movement to put data on one of the file descriptors you're selecting on, and therefore can safely use select with no timeout. The real question is what, in a real program design, might someone be expecting to do after a timeout other than call select again.

Comment: But that depends upon the situation and the application.